# OSSEC Rules Group Explanation

Tags: ossec

I am new to OSSEC and Cyber Security in general and would like to understand it a bit better. OSSEC provides so called "Rules Groups" alerts get assigned to and I would like to understand those groups a bit better.

https://www.ossec.net/docs/docs/manual/rules-decoders/rule-levels.html#rules-group

Some of the 12 groups are pretty straight forward and do not need any explanation what kind of alert gets assigned to the group. However, I do not know what the following groups mean:

```
attacks
adduser
sshd
ids
firewall
squid
apache
syslog
```

Maybe someone of you knows that and could help me out or give me something to read!
I tried to google but didnt find anything helpful.

Comment: Half of those things are easily searchable. Are you saying that you don't know what `squid` is, for instance?

Comment: Yeah this goes in the right direction. For example what type of alerts does OSSEC assign to the group of "attacks" for example

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brief explanation regarding the kind of alerts assigned to each group:

**attacks:** Events associated with attacker activity (brute force and code injection attempts for example).

**adduser:** New accounts created in the system.

**sshd:** Events associated with the Secure Shell daemon (for remote access to terminal in Linux machines)

**ids:** Alerts from Intrusion Detection Systems.

**firewall:** Events from firewall software or hardware.

**squid:** Events from the Squid proxy.

**apache:** Events from the Apache web server.

**syslog:** Syslog messages from various sources (this can be software, network devices or other syslog producing sources).